# Is there a concept called "white waveforms" in computer science?

Tags: terminology

It sounds like the [lecturer](https://youtu.be/zH2s4XSEWO0?t=150) is speaking

> If you for example want to play a
>   music file, mp3 file, well you know, given
>   that you've taken a programming course
>   before, all right? How would you do this?
>
> Well, you would look up on Wikipedia, what
>   are the specifications of an mp3 file,
>   and then you would sit down over a long
>   weekend and you could probably write
>   something in Python or in C, takes the file decodes it generates
>   the **white waveforms** and so on.
>
> and it's
>   not a big deal right after a couple days 
>   you will have a program that takes that
>   date and generates the output, that's fine.

The lecturer used a term "white waveforms".

I know the visual of a waveform may look like this figure.

[image]

I also know `.wave` is one type of audio filename extension.

I am trying to figure out what "white waveforms" is.

I understand the approximate meaning that the lecturer is trying to say is playing mp3 file.

So, what is "white waveforms"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you might have misheard.  I suspect the lecturer said "takes the file decodes it generates the **right waveforms** and so on"  (right, not white).

Comment: Right. The English R is not native to this speaker (nor is it to certain native speakers of English).

Answer (score 2):

I was listening that lecture and I think that was just a slip of the tongue. I don't think such thing exists. The closest thing coming to my mind is "**White Noise**". In signal processing, white noise is a random signal having equal intensity at different frequencies, giving it a constant power spectral density.

However, it doesn't really matter in that machine learning concept. It could be any sort of waveform.